# Why does converting string to date fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have some legacy database and it has its dates stored in `varchar` in this format e.g. `1/17/2020`

But when attempting to convert to date, it throws an error.

```
where
    Convert(date, vi.InvoiceDate, 106) between Convert(date, '1/17/2020', 103) and Convert(date, '1/17/2030', 103)
```

I tried every format, 103, 106 and more but nothing works.

Comment: It fails because there is no consistent format to the stored values - which is why it is such a poor decision to do this. You should use Gordon's suggestion to find the bad rows and update the values to correct (and convertible) ones. And then you should add logic to the system to either prevent bad values or to at least periodically scan (and maybe correct) them as some sort of admin alert.

Comment: Why use any format?  Just convert to date across the board  try_convert(date,...)

Comment: gordon's answer returns 1 what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use `try_convert()` and the correct format to see where the values fail:

```
select vi.InvoiceDate
from t
where Try_Convert(date, vi.InvoiceDate, 101) is null and
      vi.InvoiceDate is not null;
```

Note that I switched the format to `101`.  Your sample date appears to be in MM/DD/YYYY format.  You can find the list of formats in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This should be a good lesson for you on why you should store values using the correct type.  SQL Server supports date/time data types *for good reasons*.  Native types ensure that the values are valid, for instance.

Comment: It's returning 1. What does it mean?

Comment: What does "return 1" mean? Returns a single row? It will return all rows where the value is not a valid date in your expected format. While debugging, now is a good time to look at the documentation for convert. Style 103 is dd/mm - which is what you originally used (incorrectly) for your date literals.

Comment: @scaryghost . . . If it is returning the value "1", then you have an `invoiceDate` that looks like `'1'`.  No wonder it cannot be converted to a proper date!